# GCC does not work under Anaconda and Virtualenv

Tags: python, gcc, virtualenv, anaconda

I am trying to install a python packages that uses `gcc` to compile it. I can install it using `sudo` but not under a `VirtualEnv` or under `Anaconda`. I am trying to install it using `pip`. The error that I get is:

> error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Googling it I found that the usual solution is to install `python-dev` but I already have it installed.I am using Ubuntu 12.10 64 bits.

Any clues on this?

Comment: What is the name of the package? What are its dependencies (some C libraries)?

Comment: I tried [`pyraf`](http://www.stsci.edu/institute/software_hardware/pyraf) and [`statsmodels`](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I just tried to install `numpy` and got another error.

"Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to "\

SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.

Maybe it is no detecting the `python-dev` in the system.

Comment: Could you try to run `python setup.py` from the pyraf source directory and paste the output of gcc?

Comment: I paste the output of `python setup.py` [here](http://pastebin.com/Er8EMNES). It does not even get into gcc.

Comment: Now doing `python setup.py build` inside a clean Virtualenv. http://pastebin.com/s7ndxNdm

Comment: So the error displayed by `gcc` is `usr/include/string.h:548:5: error: unknown type name '__locale_t'`.

Comment: On my machine `locale_t` is defined in `/usr/include/xlocale.h`. In this header, I see the following comment: *POSIX 2008 makes locale_t official*. Could you try to add `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L` at the beginning of `src/sscanfmodule.c`?

Comment: It didn't work.

I looked in my `/usr/include/xlocale.h` and I saw the same comment as yours.

Comment: And with `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could identify the source of my problem and solve it.

The `gcc` that I was using was not the one from the system, but from another software ([MESA](http://mesa.sourceforge.net/index.html)). I was sourcing MESA from my `.bashrc` and MESA carries a version of `gcc` with it. And that was the reason of the conflict. After removing the sourcing part from the `bashrc` and restarting the shell, `gcc` return to work.